# Query Python dictionary to get value from tuple

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

Let's say that I have a Python dictionary, but the values are a tuple:

E.g.

```
dict = {"Key1": (ValX1, ValY1, ValZ1), "Key2": (ValX2, ValY2, ValZ2),...,"Key99": (ValX99, ValY99, ValY99)}
```

and I want to retrieve only the third value from the tuple, eg. ValZ1, ValZ2, or ValZ99 from the example above.

I could do so using `.iteritems()`, for instance as:

```
for key, val in dict.iteritems():
       ValZ = val[2]
```

however, is there a more direct approach?

Ideally, I'd like to query the dictionary by key and return only the third value in the tuple...

e.g.

`dict[Key1] = ValZ1` instead of what I currently get, which is `dict[Key1] = (ValX1, ValY1, ValZ1)` which is not callable...

Any advice?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just keep indexing:

```
>>> D = {"Key1": (1,2,3), "Key2": (4,5,6)}
>>> D["Key2"][2]
6
```

Answer (score 6):

Use tuple unpacking:

```
for key, (valX, valY, valZ) in dict.iteritems():
       ...
```

Often people use

```
for key, (_, _, valZ) in dict.iteritems():
       ...
```

if they are only interested in one item of the tuple. But this may cause problem if you use the `gettext` module for multi language applications, as this model sets a global function called `_`.

As tuples are immutable, you are not able to set only one item like

```
d[key][0] = x
```

You have to unpack first:

```
x, y, z = d[key]
d[key] = x, newy, z
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! A couple different options there. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Using a generator expression!

```
for val in (x[2] for x in dict):
    print val
```

You don't need to use iteritems because you're only looking at the values.